# After moving TYPO3 4.5.32 to new server - blank page

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I have a problem with move site made in TYPO3 4.5.32 (with PHP 5.2.17) to another server (with PHP 5.4.25). When I login in BE everything works fine, but when I try to open site in FE I have blank Page without any source code.

I create blank page with basic TS:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = Hello world!
}
```

with clear `Setup`, `Constance` and checked `Rootlevel` option I have blank page.

The response form server is: 200 OK

When I uncheck `Rootlevel` I have information `no TypoScript template found`.

Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A white page indicates that the script stops somewhere. I would check the memory settings in your *php.ini*. Set the `memory_limit = 512M` or take the same amount from the old server. If that not helped, you could turn on the PHP error log to see whats going on.

Comment: Hi, we change the `memory_limit` to 640 and enable PHP error log, and still the same

Comment: the cache and typo3tem folder are clear - still the same

Comment: And your PHP log don't show any errors? Can you provide more informations like which extensions are installed...

Comment: I don't have any errors - blank page and empty source code. I have lots of extension installed on this installation (+/- 300)

Comment: LOL. In this case I would deactivate ALL extension and see if its works. If it works then would going to activate them one by one again to figure out which extension causes the error.

One question: Why do you need this huge amount of extension in your TYPO3 installation?

Comment: We have huge internet portal who work on TYPO3 4.5.x version. Recently we decide to rebuild whole site and use TYPO3 6.2. We clone the installation and now have a problem to run it... Is it way to deactivate all extension at a time (not one by one)?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = Hello World
```

Here you can find a lot of nice information:
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/GettingStartedTutorial/

Comment: we have try whit this - the same situation. We are not a beginner - we create the website in TYPO3, but in this situation have problem...

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand you correctly: You like to update a full blown 300 extension TYPO3 4.5.x installation to TYPO3 6.2 on a new server?

This is an important information because there are a lot of things which changed between these two versions. I really doubt that the majority of your extensions are ready for TYPO3 6.2.

In this case I would recommend to install a 6.2 version at your new server and rebuild the portal from scratch.

> Is it way to deactivate all extension at a time (not one by one)?

After the update you already did, you should see a PackageStates.php file in */typo3conf/* folder. Copy it to somewhere else and delete it. TYPO3 should create a new one with only the basic extensions activated when you refresh the backend/frontend.

**But as I told you above. I strongly recommend you the other way around. Built your portal up from scratch.**

Comment: Not all - 1/5 of all (maybe) Built from scratch will be hard - we have more then 30000 CE with lot of dependencies between them. One more thing - I don't see any PackageStates.php in typo3conf folder (we are talking about TYPO3 4.5.x?).

Comment: I think that rebuilding the site just because it doesn't work after an update is really bad advice... how about analyzing the problem and then trying to fix it? The problem could of course turn out to be hard to solve, but that is yet to be found out. And for most TYPO3 extensions it is easy to make them compatible to a newer TYPO3 version, if the author used the API correctly.

Comment: One more thing - we will be update our TYPO3 to 6.2 in the future! Now we have TYPO3 4.5.X and we have problem with that version (not 6.2)